# Is it possible to use present perfect simple for a continuous and ongoing activity?

Tags: present-perfect

For me it's easier beccause since I have been doing music I **have always sung**  in french

in that case I have always sang  seems a continuously and ongoing action which has not stopped yet. Why not I **have been singing** to convey this idea of this ongoing continuity 
  Is it because **have been singing**  means that he is always singing 24 hours a day or is it because the present perfect progressive is used before

Comment: of course , sorry for this mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "facts on the ground" do not force us to use one expression or another. What we say expresses our view of the facts.

Both forms of the present perfect  make a statement about the world *up until now*.

You *could* use **have been *singing***:

> I have been singing in French ever since I began taking singing lessons.

to emphasize that at no time did you abandon that practice since first taking it up. It began back then and has continued.

Few native speakers would take that to mean that you have never stopped singing, not even for meals or sleep, but a comedian like Groucho Marx might ask "So how do you sleep?"

You can also use **have *sung***

> I have sung in French ever since I began taking singing lessons.

to indicate that on those occasions when you sang, it was in French, and this has been true since you began taking lessons. Groucho would not be able to make the same quip there.

Comment: So both tenses are ok in this case   .May be as the authour choose always  he preferred the present perfect simple because always indicates the continuity of ongoing action

Comment: Yes, the word **always** reinforces the idea, and it could be used with either the simple or the continuous.